# couchdb docker image: how to pre-populate database

Tags: docker, couchdb

I am creating a couchdb docker image with the following content pre-populated:

1. User name/password
2. Three databases
3. Update handler script for the above 3 databases.

I am able to do #1, but not 2 and 3.

I created an instance of couchdb with its baseline image and then created a database and added a update handler script in it. (Note - while starting couchdb instance I am using a volume)

I then did a docker commit and expected to see this database+update handler script populated in the docker image itself. However, I see it is blank.

What could be the issue here?

I understand the database and userid's are stored in the following folder:
/opt/couchdb/data

From what I understand, docker commit saves everything other than the content you store in a volume. So, the above data stored in /opt/couchdb/data should be committed to the docker image.

Any inputs on what the issue could be. Is it possible to explicitly force docker commit to save the contents of the /opt/couchdb/data folder?